# Add my applications to Vista’s Start Search

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

When you start typing in the Start Search box in Windows 7 (or Vista) Start Menu, applications are appearing in the list from which you can select them. My question is how can I add my applications so they appear in that list.

For example: I use many apps from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) like Process Explorer, AutoRun, .... I would like to launch them by starting typing and as soon as they appear in the list start the application.

Answer (score 5):

You can add it to your start menu folder to have it appear in the search box. Although from prior experience, just a shortcut sometimes doesn't work.

navigate to:

```
C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/
```

and drop your executable in there, you can even make a folder for it. Make sure it is named appropriately according to what you want to search for.

**A great alternative to the above** is [Start++](http://brandontools.com/content/StartPlusPlus.aspx), you can make custom search strings for the Vista search box:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately Start++ doesn't work on Windows 7 as advertised.  But it exactly what I'm looking for. +1

Comment: What about dropping the executable in the start menu folder?

Comment: My Windows 7 doesn't have "Start Menu" folder in C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/ directory.  However, I try to create it manually but it didn't work.

Comment: The title says vista, maybe you should make it more clear what you are actually using. The windows 7 start menu is at `C:\Users\yourUsername\Start Menu`

Answer (score 3):

I think he just meant Vista indexing his programs so when he types put, putty appears or whatever.

Comment: That was an original idea.  But I'm looking for other options too.