# How to quickly start Programs like "regedit.exe" from the Windows 7 search bar using substring matching?

Tags: windows-7

The search bar in Windows 7 is very convenient to quickly start applications by pressing the Win-key and then entering the name of the application.

For applications with a Program Menu entry like **Firefox**, it is sufficient to type **Fire** and **Firefox** will be displayed in the **Programs** section of the search results.

For other applications like `regedit.exe`, I have to type the full command **regedit** before the correct choice **regedit.exe** appears.

Is there any way to have **regedit.exe** appear already when I have just entered a substring?

**Please note**: I have seen [Add my applications to Vista’s Start Search](https://superuser.com/questions/39976/add-my-applications-to-vistas-start-search), but I don't want to add anything to the Start Menu manually. This question is about if there is some configuration that can be tuned to make the results appear.
I have also seen [Search behavior of Windows 7 start menu](https://superuser.com/questions/70333/search-behavior-of-windows-7-start-menu), but my problem is not that the exe appears under **Files**, **regedit.exe** correctly appears under **Programs**, but it should appear already for a substring match.

Comment: Use any launchers like --> www.launchy.net

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment, the question not about other launchers, but if the Windows 7 Search functionality can do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can enhance the capabilities of Windows 7 Search if you install a little freeware app called Classic Shell.

Then the Search functionality will not only list "regedit.exe" for substrings like "reg", it will also remember over time which option you launched most often for each search string and after a while you will see that option preselected by default when you type the same search string again. (It's extremely simple to implement, you just have to save some counters and do some comparisons, but it wasn't implemented)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps but there is a useful article on Technet that describes how the search function works and what can be done to improve it's capabilities:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744686%28WS.10%29.aspx#WS_SearchingfromtheStartMenu

As an alternative, you might investigate Slickrun http://www.fiddlertool.com/SlickRun/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to SlickRun, in Windows XP I also had additional "Quickstart" tools, but I was hoping that I could get rid of additional tools like that with Win7