# Windows 8 search accelerator doesn't accelerate

Tags: windows-8

The start screen search (the default Windows 8 search) will not find an application until the entire first word of the application is entered. This is inconvenient, especially if I can't remember the exact name of the application.
When I change to 'classic' start menu style I can just press the window key and type in three letters which will immediately present all applications with those three letters even if not the first three characters of the application name. Why would this search work so much better than the default, and is there a way to make the default search work the same way?

Comment: Duplicate of [windows 8 - strange behaviour when searching for an unpinned app](http://superuser.com/questions/592631/windows-8-strange-behaviour-when-searching-for-an-unpinned-app), [How to quickly start Programs like “regedit.exe” from the Windows 7 search bar using substring matching?](http://superuser.com/questions/142426/how-to-quickly-start-programs-like-regedit-exe-from-the-windows-7-search-bar-u) etc. As you can see the bug/by design behaviour pre-dates Win8. Edit: What do you mean by "'classic' start menu style" in Win8 anyway? Using a 3rd party app?

Comment: Turns out I was using a 3rd party app. Classic Shell, which was installed and turned on by Soluto. I thought Soluto was just configuring native Windows settings but that is not the case. So my conclusion is that Windows 8 'quick' app/content search is still rubbish. I recommend Classic Shell. It works very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal (rubbish) behavior of Windows 8 search. The 'classic' view and better search capability is provided by 'Classic Shell' 3rd party app, which I (and many others) recommend.